# What is the efficient algorithm to get the final state of an integer array after some range updates?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have given an array `arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`. I have to do some range updates. In each update I will be given three integers `left, right, new_value`. That means I have to update all the elements of `arr` from index `left` to `right`(0-based index) to `new_value`. Finally, I have to tell what is the final state of the array `arr` after these updates.

In this case, suppose there are 2 updates. First update says to update indexes `0...3` to `13` and second update says to update `2...6` to `0`. Final state of `arr` is `{13, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10}`.  Here is the code I tried:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        int left, right, new_value;
        cin >> left >> right >> new_value;

        for (size_t j = left; j <= right; j++)
        {
            arr[j] = new_value;
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

But the problem is if the size of the array is `n` and there are `q` queries. Then time complexity of my approach is `O(n * q).`
My question is what will be a better approach?

Comment: Are the all the queries provided ahead of time?

Comment: Yes. They are given ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create an intermediate data structure which is cheap to make range updates to.

The easiest such data structure is a tree.  One implementation could have each node of the tree contain the following fields:

```
left_index
right_index
left_subtree
right_subtree
is_constant
value
```

You can populate it in time `O(n)` by having the leaves filled in with the indexes the same, the subtrees null, `is_constant` true and the values, then fill in all of the upper levels with `is_constant` false.

Each update query just involves traversing from the top down.  The trick is that if you have set `is_constant` higher up in the tree you do NOT need to update the subtrees below it - they will all be "masked".  Thus each update is time `O(log(n))`.

Copying from the tree back to your array is again a `O(n)` operation.

The tree code will be moderately tricky, but the total time for `q` queries is `O(n) + O(q * log(n)) + O(n) = O(n + q * log(n))`.  Which is a significant improvement on `O(q * n)`.

---

Here is an outline of how the tree update works.

So we have a tree.  And we have three values, `left, right, value`.  Then the update proceeds recursively by the following Pythonish pseudocode:

```
def update_tree (self, left, right, value):
    if right < left:
        return # empty interval
    elif right < self.left_index:
        return # No overlap
    elif self.right_index < left:
        return # No overlap
    elif left <= self.left_index and self.right_index <= right:
        # No need to update the subtree - this is our win.
        self.is_constant = True
        self.value = value
    else:
        # We need to only update part of this tree.
        self.is_constant = False
        self.left_subtree.update_tree(left, right, value)
        self.right_subtree.update_tree(left, right, value)
```

Comment: I tried to use Segment tree. But couldn't get the idea how to update the tree. Please elaborate..

Comment: @YaseenMollik I added a Python version of that update logic.  Translating from Python to C++ should be easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, How can I get the final array from this tree?

Comment: Update: I got it :)

Comment: `right <= self.right_index and self.left_index <= left` isn't this backwards? I assumed `self` is the current tree interval, so an overlap for a later update, which is supposed to dominate the current tree interval, would have its right >= self.right_index and its left <= self.left_index. Could you please help me understand? Alternatively, if the later interval is smaller than the current tree interval, how can we justify setting the entire current interval to a new value?

Comment: @YaseenMollik Please note the right/left switch.  It makes a pretty big difference. :-(

Comment: @btilly I thought I got it. But I didn't. How to finally get the array from the tree? I need help :)

Comment: @YaseenMollik A recursive search from the top.  If `is_constant`, just put `value` in for the range of indexes, otherwise call the recursive function on the left and the right.

Comment: @btilly  [link](https://ideone.com/0PG5yE) Whats the problem here? If initially a[4] = {0,0,0,0} is the array and the updates are {0,3,4}, {0,2,3}, {0,1, 1}. Here first two number of each tuple is the range and last one is the value. It should give outpur {3, 1, 4, 0} instead it gives {0, 1, 4, 0}

Comment: @YaseenMollik In `Update` you wanted `if (start > r || end < l)`.  Currently you have `end < r` in that condition.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this efficiently is to maintain an ordered collection that stores the values for just index 0 and those indexes with values that are different from the previous index.

Since you're using C++, you can put index -> value mappings in an `std::map<int,int>`.

On each update you spend **O(log n)** time to find the position to modify the map (with `map.lower_bound`), and then you will add at most 2 entries, and maybe delete some pre-existing entries or some entries that you've added before.

The total number of prexisting entries is **<= n**, the total number of entries you add is **<= 2q**, and the total number of entries you delete is therefore **<= n + 2q**.

All together the total complexity is **O(n + q * log n)**

Comment: Huh.  Reading http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/ I see that actually erasing  `k` values from a `map` takes time `O(k)`.  I would have guessed a `log(n)` factor in there.  Live and learn!

Comment: @btilly: I'm sure it's actually O(max(k, log n)), because otherwise it would be faster to delete a single element by pretending it's a range.

Comment: @ruakh When I said "actually erasing" I mean the "removing from the data structure" bit of the operation.  The full operation of course also needs `O(log(n))` to find where to do that, so you are right.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans, If initially a[4] = {0,0,0,0}  is the array and the updates are {0,3,4}, {0,2,3}, {0,1, 1}. Here first two number of each tuple is the range and last one is the value. How can your approach be applied here?

Comment: @YaseenMollik the map is initially populated with {0->0}.  After 0,3,4 it's {0->4, 4->0}.  Then {0->3 ,3->4, 4->0}.  Then {0->1, 2->3, 3->4, 4->0}

Answer (score 1):

This also seems a case for a priority queue. Associate each left and right parts of the query with the appropriate array cell.

```
[(13,1), 2, (0,2), (-13,1), 5,
 6, (-0,2), 8, 9, 10]

(If more than one fall on one cell,
 aggregate them.)
```

Now, as we traverse from left to right, we're interested in one thing: which update interval we are currently in (if any) is provided in the queries last? The latter "rank" is the query-part's priority.

We start with (13,1), which we place in the priority queue and keep output-ing 13 until we reach (0,2). We add (0,2) to the priority queue, which takes greater priority. We continue output-ing 0. We reach (-13,1), which tells us to remove (13,1) from the priority queue, and continue to putput 0 until (-0,2) calls for removing (0,2). We end with 8,9,10.

Answer (score 0):

Apply interval algebra to your queries.  A new query takes precedence over old ones.  In your posted situation you start with a clean sheet.  The first query adds the transaction

```
0   3    13
```

The second one updates this table to

```
0   1    13     // note the range change -- intervals may not overlap
2   6     0
```

Most languages have interval modules that will support such operations for you.  Your table is sorted, such that a search is no worse than **O(log q)** for each endpoint of a new query -- and a direct indexing method will drop this to **O(n)**.

Do not make any updates until you're out of queries.  The interval process is **O(q)**, and the update is **O(n)**, so your overall complexity is **O(q+n)**.

Comment: Would you please elaborate?

Comment: "Elaborate" in what direction?  Where are you not following?